# Get pointer to unmanaged memory in C# from C++

Tags: c#, pointers, pinvoke, intptr

I've been given a C++ DLL that allocates memory.  It has several functions that need me to pass it the pointer to this allocated memory.  I'm working in C# so I need to keep this pointer around, so I can pass it back to the C++ DLL when needed.  The pointer will never be used in the C# side other than keeping it around to pass to the C++ code.

I'd prefer not to use the `unsafe` keyword at all.

I've created an IntPtr to pass to the C++ functions to store the allocated memory address, but it crashes immediately on the C++ side (AccessViolationException).  I'm not sure of the proper syntax for the DLL call.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
[DllImport("data_accessor.dll")]
public static extern void get_pointer_to_new_memory(IntPtr memory_ptr);
```

Is this possible without using `unsafe`?  If so, how?

UPDATE:
Sorry I didn't post this sooner.  Here is the function I'm calling. (Names have been changed to protect the innocent.)

```
typedef void* handle_ptr;
void DLL_API get_pointer_to_new_memory(handle_ptr* handle)
```

Comment: `IntPtr` is the way to go - and you don't need `unsafe` for that. As for your exception, make sure the function signatures match, **and** also make sure you're using the correct [calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention.aspx).

Comment: Wait... given the name of the function from your example, I'd expect either `IntPtr get_pointer_to_new_memory()` or `void get_pointer_to_new_memory(out IntPtr memory_ptr)`.

Comment: Can you post the signature of the actual c++ function please

Comment: This kind of interop is all about matching two versions of a function. You only showed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lucas' comment I got it working.  I was on the right track...just missing the `out` keyword.

```
[DllImport("data_accessor.dll")]
public static extern void get_pointer_to_new_memory(out IntPtr memory_ptr);
```